# Why my haskell program is too slow?

Tags: haskell

I tried to solve Problem 443 on ProjectEuler, https://projecteuler.net/problem=443.

To find pattern of g, I simply implemented g in Haskell as

```
g::Int->Int
g 4=13
g n=g (n-1)+n `gcd` g(n-1)
```

But computing list `t=[g i|i<-[4..100]]` takes much more than 1 second.
Why this happens? Even without memoization, it takes only O(n) for each g(n).

Edit: when I tried this code in ideone, it's fine, but in my computer it's not. Is that haskell version problem? I'm using version ghc 7.8.3 on Windows, while ideone using ghc 7.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it takes only O(n) for each g(n)

Not exactly. In your recursive case

> ```
> g n=g (n-1)+n `gcd` g(n-1)
> ```

you are calling `g` *twice*. Which means you are getting exponential runtime actually (`O(2n)`).

To make sure that `g (n-1)` is evaluated only once in each step, use a `let` or `where` statement so that you can refer to a single value - the result of the one call - twice.

```
g :: Int -> Int
g 4 = 13
g n = let r = g (n-1)
      in r + n `gcd` r
```

> when I tried this code in ideone, it's fine, but in my computer it's not. Is that haskell version problem?

Possibly, although rather an optimisation level parameter problem. Haskell's compiler can optimise functions such as yours when it detects that an expression (like `g (n-1)`) appears twice, but searching for these is costly and needs to be enabled.

Comment: Why my code is not memoizied? Only my guess is haskell tried to compute g parallelly so it takes exponential time. Is that right?

Comment: @Maddy It is a common, but baffling, misconception that Haskell automatically memoizes.  No other language (more accurately: compiler) I know of does so and Haskell (GHC) is not so vastly different as many articles might lead you to believe.

Answer (score 5):

If you change the definition of `g` to:

```
g::Int->Int
g 4=13
g n=x+n `gcd` x
  where x = g (n-1)
```

then I get acceptable run times even under `ghci` or `runhaskell` (as opposed to `ghc -O2`.)